# Validating list element in Python

Tags: python, list, validation

I'm trying to validate each element as it is inputted to make sure no name is less than 2 digits. I'm assuming no name exists with just 2 characters. Spaces or last names don't matter.

I'm getting a list index out of range error.

```
#The getValidateNames function takes 20 names as input,validates them, sorts list and returns list.
def getValidateNames():
  nameList = []    #Create empty list variable.
  counter = 1      #Loop counter

  #Loop through and prompt for 20 names.
  while counter <=20:
    nameList.append(input("Please enter name #{}:".format(counter)))
    if nameList[counter] < 2:
      print("You have entered an invalid name.")
      nameList.append(input("Please try again: "))
  counter += 1

  nameList.sort()
  return nameList
```

Comment: Why are you appending before testing? Should it not be other way around.

Comment: use the `len()` function to check the size of the `string`, make the name input a variable to store it, and then check for its size

Comment: List indexes start at zero. But counter - the variable you're using to index `nameList` - is initially set to `1`.

Comment: Initialize the `counter` to 0

Comment: Thanks. I set counter to 0 and I'm going to store input in variable, validate it and then if good add it to list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List indexes start at zero in Python. So the first index of `nameList` is `0` not `1`. So because you initialized `counter` to `1` and then tried to index `nameList`, Python raised an `IndexError`.

However, there is still a problem with your code. doing `nameList[counter] > 2` is not comparing the length of the string at index `counter` in `nameList`. It is simply comparing the string itself to the integer `2` which really doesn't make sense. You need to use the `len()` builtin function to get the length of the string:

```
counter = 0

while counter <=20:
    ...
    if len(nameList[counter]) < 2:
        ...
    ...
```